# Reverse port forward with EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, reverse-tunnel

I have two computer behind NATs so I thought of using a free tier EC2 server as a SSH relay.

Followed this simple tutorial http://www.acooke.org/cute/ReverseRem0.html which seemed pretty reasonable.

Now I have my server listening `2222` port:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 22222
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:2222    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
tcp    0    :::2222           ::::*        LISTEN
```

And I think I have the security groups properly configured on Amazon:

```
Security Groups associated with myserver (myserver)
Ports   Protocol    Source  quick-start-1
0   icmp    0.0.0.0/0   
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   
2222    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

But it is still not possible to connect to that port from the internet.

Some other facts:
I know there isn't any "filter" between me and amazon on port 2222 (works for some other servers)
The command used to create the tunnel was `ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 ec2-user@myserver`

Have I missed anything?

Comment: I think you need to add the -g flag to allow for remote hosts to connect to the forwarded port, since it sounds like you're going to be using a second machine to connect to the ec-2 instance to get back to the first machine, correct?

Comment: I have actually edited my sshd_config with `GatewayPorts yes`. From what I read it should be enough... Will give a try though.

Comment: On which server did you edit the `sshd_config`?

Comment: uh, good point. did that on the EC2 only. Will try to update that on my local server.

Comment: No, not really. Tried it all: `GatewayPorts yes` in both servers *and* used `-g` flag. Still can't connect.